# jquery masked input plugin set value digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, input-mask

```
$(".id").mask("999-99-9999-999-99");
```

I have the above mask input format i want to know if it is possible to have a predefined value for x number of characters like for example

I want the first 5 letters to have a default and unchangeable numbers.

Sample number will be

`639-27-9999-999-99`

here the numbers `639-27-` should be always there meaning when the input has focus it will automatically be put there and cannot be changed.

`F.Y.I`

[Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: You can do it like this using the plugin: $(".id").mask("639-27-9999-999-99"); As they used 9 as their number definition, you can change it in their source code with any other character.

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury you can post it as answer so i can tick it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround solution might be,

```
$.mask.definitions["9"] = null;
$.mask.definitions["^"] = "[0-9]";
$(".id").mask("639-27-^^^-^^^-^^");
```

1. remove the definition for `9`
2. add a definition for numeric regex with a new key ex. `^`
3. use the new definition

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzqrr0qm/)

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using the plugin: `$(".id").mask("639-27-9999-999-99");` As they used 9 as their number definition, you can change it in their source code with any other character.