# jquery mask input plugin only set day value of the date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using masked-input-plugin. Only day part need to change but month and year not need to change. Here is my code.

```
$("#id").mask("99/06/2017",{placeholder:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
```

During the input time :
it seeing like `dd/06/2017` but if I select the input box then remove the cursor(without pressing any number) that time it's show something like as `06/06/2017`

I have seen 
[this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862088/jquery-masked-input-plugin-set-value-digits)

I am very sorry for my poor English.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I am able to solve the problem. I am posting this answer, so anybody can get help.

Firstly, extend the mask function of the mask input plugin. Then customized some code to solve this problem.

`For the solution please visit` [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharghoshbd/kdLxwtfo/23/)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of

```
$('#dob').mask("00/00/0000",{placeholder:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
```

this will solve your problem

Comment: This solution actually not solve the problem. It's not a proper solution. Still now I am searching the solution for this problem.

Comment: what is the reason you put "99/06/2017" in the masking?

Comment: Please go through http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ . I just want to input the day part not the month and year part. This answer not able to solve my issue.